# Как получить два значения по ключу?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$users = User::where(['role' => 'admin'])->get();
```

Как кроме `'role' => 'admin'` получить, например, `'role' => 'user'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй так:

```
$users = User::where(['or', 'role="admin"','role="user"'])->get();
```

или, возможно, так:

```
$users = User::where(['role' => 'admin'])
         ->orWhere(['role' => 'user']) // ->andWhere(['role' => 'user'])
         ->get();
```

Comment: Второй вариант подошел! Спасибо!